# Can i send a json object to restApi without using cookies in angular 2+

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to send a json type object to the rest service in a (angular2+ springMvc + java) web project, But it seems quiet difficult. Also i am not able to use cookie too.

Comment: Add more Information and try to tell what you tried and what was isuues

Comment: Here: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/ i used this guide to get an overview about the possibilities, but don't forget also to read this: https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04

Comment: issue:I cant pass the json object from angular side to the rest service.Also After getting that object from rest then need to do some modifications and again i need to send it to the backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I got from your question, you are trying to figure out a way to handle http requests in your Angular project.

Let's have a look at your project structure first. You have to have a separate directory in which you have all the services related to the given module is in.

In that directory, you can create services using `ng g s service-name` and in this case to handle http requests.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import {environment} from "../../../../environments/environment";

const BASE_URL = environment.API_PATH;
const WAR = environment.API_WAR;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceNameService {
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
    })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getCall() {
    return this.http.get(`${BASE_URL}/${WAR}/your/path/all`);
  }

  getByIdCall(id) {
    return this.http.get(`${BASE_URL}/${WAR}/your/path?id=${id}`);
  }

  deleteByIdCall(id) {
    return this.http.delete(`${BASE_URL}/${WAR}/your/path/delete?id=${id}`);
  }

  postCall(payload: any) {
    return this.http.post(`${BASE_URL}/${WAR}/your/path/save`, payload);
  }

  putCall(id, payload) {
    return this.http.put(`${BASE_URL}/${WAR}/your/path/update?id=${id}`, payload);
  }

}
```

Now you have to call this in the component, you want to perform http requests.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ServiceNameService} from '../../../services/http-services/service-name.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-config-view',
  templateUrl: './config-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./config-view.component.scss']
})
export class ConfigViewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private serviceNameService: ServiceNameService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loadAll() {
    this.serviceNameService.getCall()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
          console.log(data);
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

  loadById(id) {
    this.serviceNameService.getByIdCall(id)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
          console.log(data);
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

  deleteById(id) {
    this.serviceNameService.deleteByIdCall(id)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
          console.log(data);
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

  save() {
    const payload = {
      test: "test value"
    }
    this.serviceNameService.postCall(payload)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
          console.log(data);
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

  update() {
    const payload = {
      test: "test value updated"
    }
    this.serviceNameService.putCall(id, payload)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
          console.log(data);
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

}
```

Now you can call these methods as you want.

Hope this helps!

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just remember to set the proper content-type header

```
constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

   this.http.post(<url>, {jsonData}, { headers });
}
```